# Fail to compile dev86 package on gentoo

Tags: compiler-errors, virtualbox, gentoo

When i try to install virtualbox I have following error during compile dev86 package:

```
00159                                           mov     spbbp
***** comma expected.........................................^
***** factor expected........................................^
***** illegal indirect to indirect...........................^

00091 errors
00000 warnings
make[4]: *** [__ldivmod.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/dev86-0.16.18/work/dev86-0.16.18/libc/bcc'
make[3]: *** [/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/dev86-0.16.18/work/dev86-0.16.18/libc/libc.a] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/dev86-0.16.18/work/dev86-0.16.18/libc'
make[2]: *** [library] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/dev86-0.16.18/work/dev86-0.16.18'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/dev86-0.16.18/work/dev86-0.16.18'
make: *** [all] Error 2
emake failed
 * ERROR: sys-devel/dev86-0.16.18 failed (compile phase):
 *   (no error message)
 *
```

I tried to downgrade make to v3.81, use older version of dev86 and use  but it didn't help.
I tried with -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE in cflags and cxxflags, but also nothing changed.

```
gentoo herman # emerge --info dev86
Portage 2.1.10.65 (default/linux/amd64/10.0, gcc-4.5.3, glibc-2.15-r2, 3.3.1-gentoo x86_64)
=================================================================
                        System Settings
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-3.3.1-gentoo-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-2_Duo_CPU_T9400_@_2.53GHz-with-gentoo-2.1
Timestamp of tree: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 15:45:01 +0000
ccache version 3.1.7 [enabled]
app-shells/bash:          4.2_p20
dev-java/java-config:     2.1.11-r3
dev-lang/python:          2.7.2-r3, 3.2.2
dev-util/ccache:          3.1.7
dev-util/cmake:           2.8.8-r3
dev-util/pkgconfig:       0.26
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.1
sys-apps/openrc:          0.9.8.4
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.5
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.13, 2.68
sys-devel/automake:       1.11.3, 1.12.1
sys-devel/binutils:       2.22-r1
sys-devel/gcc:            4.5.3-r2, 4.6.3
sys-devel/gcc-config:     1.7.3
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4.2
sys-devel/make:           3.82-r3
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 3.2 (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.15-r2
Repositories: gentoo
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64 ~amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="*"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=core2 -mcx16 -msahf -msse4.1 --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=6144 -mtune=generic"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/config /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt /usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0 /var/lib/hsqldb"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="${EPREFIX}/etc/gconf /etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/env.d/java/ /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/php/apache2-php5.3/ext-active/ /etc/php/apache2-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/php/cgi-php5.3/ext-active/ /etc/php/cgi-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/php/cli-php5.3/ext-active/ /etc/php/cli-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/revdep-rebuild /etc/sandbox.d /etc/splash /etc/terminfo"
CXXFLAGS="-march=core2 -mcx16 -msahf -msse4.1 --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=6144 -mtune=generic"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs ccache config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles news parallel-fetch parse-eapi-ebuild-head protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch"
FFLAGS=""
GENTOO_MIRRORS="http://ftp.vectranet.pl/gentoo/ http://gentoo.mirror.pw.edu.pl/"
LANG="pl_PL.utf8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
LINGUAS="pl"
MAKEOPTS="-j5"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
PORTDIR="/usr/portage"
PORTDIR_OVERLAY=""
SYNC="rsync://rsync7.pl.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage"
USE="X aac aacplus acl acpi alsa amd64 amr apache2 aperfmperf apic apng arch_perfmon asf ass avx berkdb bts bzip2 cleartype clflush cli cmov consolekit constant_tsc corefonts cpudetection cracklib crypt cups custom-cflags cx16 cx8 cxx dbus de declarative dirac djvu dri ds_cpl dtes64 dts dvd encode est ffmpeg flexpriority fontconfig fortran fpu fxsr gd gdbm gles gpm gtk gtk3 gudev hardcoded-tables ht iconv icu jack java jpeg kde kipi lahf_lm libnotify lm lm_sensors mca mce minizip mmx mmxext mng modules monitor mp3 msr mtrr mudflap multilib multimedia mysql ncurses nls nopl nptl nsplugin nx ogg opengl openmp pae pam pat pbe pcre pdcm pdf pdfimport pebs pge php png pni policykit ppds pppd pse pse36 python qalculate qt-faststart qt3support qt4 qwt rdesktop readline rep_good samba scanner schroedinger semantic-desktop sep session smx source spell sql ss sse sse2 sse4_1 ssl ssse3 static-libs subvesion svg syscall tcpd threads tm tm2 tools tpr_shadow truetype tsc type1 udev unicode upower usb vhosts vme vmx vnmi vorbis webkit wicd wifi win32codec wma-fixed x264 xinerama xorg xosd xtpr xvid zeroconf zlib" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" ALSA_PCM_PLUGINS="adpcm alaw asym copy dmix dshare dsnoop empty extplug file hooks iec958 ioplug ladspa lfloat linear meter mmap_emul mulaw multi null plug rate route share shm softvol" APACHE2_MODULES="actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="kexi words flow plan sheets stage tables krita karbon braindump" CAMERAS="ptp2" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="mouse keyboard evdev synaptics" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" LINGUAS="pl" NETBEANS_MODULES="php websvccommon" PHP_TARGETS="php5-3" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_2 python2_7" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby18 ruby19" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="nvidia" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS, USE_PYTHON
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question really belongs over at serverfault.com

Comment: By the way, this is the most exotic set of `CFLAGS` I've ever seen in a make.conf. I'd start by changing those to something more conventional, like `CFLAGS="-march=core2 -O2 -pipe"` and try this compile again.

Comment: Thx for your reply :-) I've changed the CFLAGS but still same error :/

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to build the `sys-devel/dev86-0.16.18` package on 5 hardened gentoo amd64 machines, and they all succeeded.

Although the package displays a lot of warnings during compilation and an abundance of QA Notices afterwards, which might very well be the cause of your issues:

```
 * QA Notice: Package triggers severe warnings which indicate that it
 *            may exhibit random runtime failures.
 * floatop.c:33:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
 * floatop.c:48:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
 * genloads.c:391:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
 * genloads.c:395:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
 * loadexp.c:79:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules


 * QA Notice: Package triggers severe warnings which indicate that it
 *            may exhibit random runtime failures.
 * dbprintf.c:24:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘vdbprintf’
 * dbprintf.c:30:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘write’
 * dbprintf.c:110:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlen’
 * dumps.c:22:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memcmp’
 * dumps.c:25:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlen’
 * ld.c:221:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ld86r’
 * mkar.c:41:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fatalerror’


 * QA Notice: Package triggers severe warnings which indicate that it
 *            may exhibit random runtime failures.
 * dbprintf.c:110:13: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
 * dumps.c:25:6: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’

 * QA Notice: Package triggers severe warnings which indicate that it
 *            may exhibit random runtime failures.
 * input.c:400:10: warning: array subscript is below array bounds


 * QA Notice: Package triggers severe warnings which indicate that it
 *            may exhibit random runtime failures.
 * makeboot.c:1247:7: warning: too few arguments for format

 * Please do not file a Gentoo bug and instead report the above QA
 * issues directly to the upstream developers of this software.
 * Homepage: http://www.debath.co.uk/
```

If your toolchain is too 'strict' or incorrectly configured it might easily break on the packages poor coding. As I've mentioned in my previous comment, your `CFLAGS` don't follow the 'safe' values as recommended by the [Gentoo Wiki on your CPU architecture](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Safe_Cflags/Intel#Core_2_Duo.2FQuad.2C_Xeon_51xx.2F53xx.2F54xx.2F3360.2C_Pentium_Dual-Core_T23xx.2B.2FExxxx.2C_Celeron_Dual-Core), which recommends the following settings for your CPU:

```
64 bit profile (amd64) for >= GCC 4.3

CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=core2 -O2 -pipe"
CXXFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
```

It might be required to recompile your toolchain with more conservative `CFLAGS`.

But before you do so (which takes a lot of time obviously) you might try some of the stuff that usually works when encountering compilation errors:

1. Make sure your system is up to date and all packages are in sync:

   `emerge --sync && emerge -uDNav --with-bdeps=y @world`
2. Resolve any discrepancies with old packages and broken libraries:

   `emerge --depclean && revdep-rebuild`
3. Switch back to stable packages. I've noticed that you run with `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64 ~amd64"`, which can cause unexpected problems beyond unstable packages. You might want to try removing `~amd64` from there and declare that you want unstable versions of specific packages in `/etc/portage/package.keywords` ([See the Gentoo Manual on this subject](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=3&chap=3)). After setting the correct flags retry steps 1 & 2.

If building this package still fails and you haven't given up yet you can move on to rebuilding the toolchain by:

1. First setting the `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and other directives like `USE` and `LDFLAGS` to safe values in `/etc/make.conf`.
2. Recompile GCC with the new configuration and make sure the correct version is selected for use:

   ```
   emerge gcc
   gcc-config -l 
   [1] i686-pc-linux-gnu-4.4.5 * 
   [2] i686-pc-linux-gnu-4.5.3
   gcc-config 2
   env-update && source /etc/profile
   ```
3. Rebuild the remainder of the toolchain (Reference: [Upgrading GCC](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gcc-upgrading.xml) and [Upgrading Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/new-upgrade-to-gentoo-1.4.xml)):

   ```
   emerge libtool glibc binutils
   ```
4. Have some coffee, watch a movie, come back and retry your initial compile.

Running through all steps above is time consuming, but solves most `emerge` compilation errors (if the package itself isn't broken ofcourse).

As a reference, here is the `emerge --info` for a sane (hardened) machine that succeeds compiling this package:

```
Portage 2.1.10.49 (hardened/linux/amd64, gcc-4.5.3, glibc-2.14.1-r3, 3.2.2-hardened-r1-RMZv1si x86_64)
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-3.2.2-hardened-r1-RMZv1si-x86_64-Intel-R-_Xeon-TM-_CPU_3.40GHz-with-gentoo-2.1
Timestamp of tree: Fri, 15 Jun 2012 08:00:01 +0000
app-shells/bash:          4.2_p20
dev-java/java-config:     2.1.11-r3
dev-lang/python:          2.7.3-r2, 3.2.3
dev-util/cmake:           2.8.7-r5
dev-util/pkgconfig:       0.26
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.1-r1
sys-apps/openrc:          0.9.8.4
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.5
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.13, 2.68
sys-devel/automake:       1.4_p6-r1, 1.11.1
sys-devel/binutils:       2.21.1-r1
sys-devel/gcc:            4.5.3-r2
sys-devel/gcc-config:     1.6
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4-r1
sys-devel/make:           3.82-r1
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 3.1 (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.14.1-r3
Repositories: gentoo x-boxed-main kormoc x-portage
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="*"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=nocona -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa /var/bind /var/qmail/alias /var/qmail/control /var/vpopmail/etc"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/env.d/java/ /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/php/apache2-php5.3/ext-active/ /etc/php/apache2-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/php/cgi-php5.3/ext-active/ /etc/php/cgi-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/php/cli-php5.3/ext-active/ /etc/php/cli-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/revdep-rebuild /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo"
CXXFLAGS="-march=nocona -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles news parallel-fetch protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch"
FFLAGS=""
GENTOO_MIRRORS="ftp://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/gentoo http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/gentoo ftp://mirror.leaseweb.com/gentoo/ http://mirror.leaseweb.com/gentoo/ "
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS="-j5"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
PORTDIR="/usr/portage"
PORTDIR_OVERLAY="/var/lib/layman/boxed-main /var/lib/layman/kormoc /usr/local/portage"
SYNC="rsync://rsync.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage"
USE="acl amd64 apache2 auth_digest bash bash-completion bzip2 caps cli cracklib crypt ctype cxx dba dri ftp gd gdbm gpm hardened iconv imap innodb intl ipv6 ithreads jpeg jpeg2k justify memcache memcached mmx modules mudflap multilib mysql ncurses nls nptl openmp pam pax_kernel pcre php pic png pppd raw readline session slang snmp sockets sse sse2 ssl suexec svg tcpd threads tiff unicode urandom usagi valias vhosts vpopmail wmf xml xorg zlib" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" ALSA_PCM_PLUGINS="adpcm alaw asym copy dmix dshare dsnoop empty extplug file hooks iec958 ioplug ladspa lfloat linear meter mmap_emul mulaw multi null plug rate route share shm softvol" APACHE2_MODULES="actions alias authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_dbd authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation setenvif speling ssl status unique_id usertrack auth_basic auth_digest rewrite userdir vhost_alias bw bandwidth cgid" APACHE2_MPMS="prefork" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="kexi words flow plan sheets stage tables krita karbon braindump" CAMERAS="ptp2" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="keyboard mouse evdev" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" PHP_TARGETS="php5-4" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_2 python2_7" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby18 ruby19" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="fbdev glint intel mach64 mga neomagic nouveau nv r128 radeon savage sis tdfx trident vesa via vmware dummy v4l" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, INSTALL_MASK, LINGUAS, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS, USE_PYTHON
```

Good luck!